# OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 Mssing

Tags: ssis

I have deployed SSIS package that fetch data from Microsoft Access database. it works fine Locally and on Server i am running it using DTESEX 32 bit but getting following error

The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.

How can i make sure that OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 exist on server

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe Access needs to be installed onto your server as well if you want to use that OLEDB provider

Comment: @mituw16 You are ;) There is a specific driver they can download that is not a full-blown MS Office installation. Well, at least for the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 I'm not familiar with a 15 release being out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try installing the [Access 2013 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358) on the server, which should enable the use of that provider (at least in 32-bit).

The exception indicates that it is not able to find the OLE DB provider specified, which can be installed through standard Access installations or by installing the runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I tried importing data from 64bit excel file into SQL using SSMS's import wizard and got got this error :microsoft ace oledb 15.0 provider is not registered on the local machine.

One of my colleagues showed me to use 64bit import wizard rather than 32 bit defualt import wizard that I have in SSMS. Here is a short video I posted about successfully loading the data on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIs-vbaGSzg

Comment: You did not post the error, and the code you used in your attempt. Most people are not going to watch a video to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, I posted the solution in the video after I got this error. Thank you for your comment

Comment: agreed...  posting the actual information rather than only the link is not only my preference, but is strongly encouraged on SO.  One of the goals of the site is to be self contained --  definitely post links to evidence supporting your answer, but include all the answer information in your SO post.

Answer (score 3):

Per @Gaurav Saneja's answer, you can use the "SQL Server 2016 Import and Export Data (64-bit)" (found in start menu). SSMS is 32-bit, so it attempts to load the 32-bit version of the DLL, but fails because you (likely) have the 64 bit version of Office installed.

Some people are recommending the installation of **AccessRuntime_x86_en-us.exe** from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358 
however, for me this fails with the error:

> We can't install the 32-bit version of Office because we found the following 64-bit programs on your PC: `-list of installed Office apps here-`

[image: Image of installation error message]

Until Microsoft provides a 64-bit version of SSMS, we are stuck using the method of launching the 64-bit version of the Data Import wizard independently (as described above).

Comment: try installing with "AccessRuntime_x86_en-us.exe /passive"

Comment: @CoderBrien Using that switch still didn't allow me to install the 32-bit version on a machine with 64-bit Office applications already installed.

Comment: @PhilipStratford It may not work with the latest version (office 2016).  I know it works with access 2010.

Comment: awesome...   worked for me -- SSMS 17.8.1 and Access 2013 64bit.  I agree with @CoderBrien that installing the 2010 runtime used to do it... I think I have my own answer on here about it :-p

Answer (score 1):

**Environment:**
Machine (64bit)
Operating System Windows 10 Pro (64bit)
Visual Studio 2017 (32bit)
Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) (32bit)
Office 2016 (64bit)

Attempted to use Excel in SSIS.  Received the following errors:  when I select 2016 or 2013 in connection manager.  Issue to be resolved.
Error for 2016:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C Error at Package:  The requested
>   OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered.  If the
>   32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error
>   code: 0x00000000. An OLE DB record is available.   Source: "Microsoft
>   OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class
>   not registered".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.   The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209302.   There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

**Error for 2013:**

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C Error at Package:  The requested
>   OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 is not registered.  If the
>   32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error
>   code: 0x00000000. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
>   OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class
>   not registered".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.   The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209302.   There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

**Solution:**
Installed the following: 
I needed 64bit Access Database Engine 2016 Redistribution for another portion of the project.  Unstalling it was not a solution, but the 2007 Data connectivity component and Data Access Engine 2016 can live side by side:
2007 (USE 32bit) : 2007 Office System Driver Data Connectivity Components
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

2016 (USE 64bit) : Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
Finally:
Inside of Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) follow the following instructions to Adjust Project:

1. Open SSIS project
2. Select the project in Solution Explorer
3. Select Properties
4. Expand Configuration Properties in the left pane
5. Click Debugging and change Run64BitRuntime to False
6. Click OK

**Adjust Connection Manager:**
 7. Open Excel Connection Manager
 8. Click the drop-down menu. Excel Options work:Excel 97-2003 and Excel 2007-2010
 9.  Click Ok

**Open Excel Source component:**
 10. Select the Excel connection manager
 11. Select Table View from Data Access Mode
 12. Select Excel Sheet

You should be able to Preview the data in the Excel sheet